# Flutter WEB: Detect when app is killed (window/tab is closed)

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Is there a way to detect when a Flutter WEB app is killed ?
I found that it's possible to use 'onBeforeUnload':

```
html.window.onBeforeUnload.listen((event) async{
  // do something
});
```

But I can't figure out how to use it.
I'm in need of obtain the session time duration of a user and send data with a ws when window is closed.

If someone could help me with an example of how to use onBeforeUnload(), it'll be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be casted into the `BeforeUnloadEvent` before setting the returnValue

```
import 'dart:html' as html;

...

html.window.onBeforeUnload.listen((event) {
  if (event is html.BeforeUnloadEvent) {
    event.returnValue = 'Some return value here';
  }
});
```